# Connect in Oracle localhost

Tags: java, android, oracle

**Oracle is IP:** ps-server-dom

**Port:** 1521

```
Usado o adaptador HOSTNAME para resolver o apelido
Tentativa de contatar (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTO
COL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.101)(PORT=1521)))
OK (10 ms)
```

**ERROR:**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Exceção de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

**Code:**

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();;
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ps-server-dom:1521:PSYS", "psyst", "psyst");
```

Answer (score 0):

check listener.ora, tnsnames.ora has the correct settings.If you want to access it with 'ps-server-dom' then these files should have this particular host name rather than the ip address.

following shows possible settings of these files for oracle xe.

tnsnames.ora

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ps-server-dom)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

listener.ora

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ps-server-dom)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

note: if you are in some domain then HOST=ps-server-dom.yourdomain.com. 
these files are located under '`oraclexe\app\oracle\product\<version>\server\network\ADMIN`' in windows.